# QTP Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qtp

I am working with QTP Test automation. As QTP seeks high costly lience, my team wants to move from QTP to to arealible TEST automation Suite developer software. Our main requirments are Version Control, Source code control. I am new to Visual Studio, is GIT free of cost?

We do hardware test automation.

Please make quiick suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please consider closing the question, adding and accepting your own answer, or accepting my answer. Don´t let this lure around forever, please.

Answer (score 1):

Test Design Studio from Patternson Consulting is a quite high-priced but good-looking IDE alternative for QTP, see http://www.patterson-consulting.net/products/Default.aspx. (I haven´t used it ever, and I am not part of the software maker.)

It might be worth the money because the IDE appears to be much better, and it allows you to avoid using a QTP license for all development steps. Most things can be done in Test Design Studio, biggest gap seems to be .tsr file editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have visual studio you can use the VSTS.( Coded UI).